# How would I design a State Diagram (FSM) for a AC unit?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Ok so I'm learning Finite Automata in my Theory of Computation course and understand the basic FSM but can't wrap my head around this question:
The AC should only turn on if a person is
detected in the room and the temperature is hot (80 degrees or higher). It turns off when no one is detected in the room, the window is open, or the temperature is cold (32 degrees or lower).

Comment: Do you have any questions/confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Your question's answer could be solved by Finite Automata with output that is Moore Machine or Mealy Machine.

You have three cases:

$Case:1$ When temperature is equal or more than $80°$ then output is $1$(Turn on) which is associated with state i.e.$(q_i, 1).$

$Case:2$ When temperature is less than $32°$ then output is $0$(Turn off) which is associated with state i.e.$(q_i, 0).$

$Case:3$ When temperature between $32°$ and $80°$ then output is $a$(No action) which is associated with state i.e.$(q_i, a).$

I have designed Moore Machine where output is associated with state. [image]

State $q_7$ falls under $case:1$ and states $q_6, q_{16}$ falls under $case:3$ and remaining states falls under $case:2.$

N. B. -- The binary representation of $80$ and $32$ is $1010000$  and $100000$ respectively.You have to design Mealy Machine by your own which is your homework. Simply just convert Moore Machine to Mealy from my diagram.